# Would this language be regular?

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

$$A = \{a^{2j+3}b^{k+r+4}c^{2s+3}  \mid  j \geq k \geq 0, r \geq 0, s \geq 0\}$$

I'm assuming this is a regural language even though $k$ depends on $j$ because the amount of $a$'s has no correlation to the amount of $b$'s due to the $r$ term added into the exponent of $b$. Do you guys agree with this assumption?

Thank you. I'm new to the site I'm not sure if my syntax is perfect with the formula, sorry about that.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, you have to put a backslash in front of curly brackets though. Regarding the regularity I find that your assumption is correct. The number of $b$s seems to depend not on the number of $a$s.

Comment: Right! $k$ might as well be zero, and nothing will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Show that your language is equal to $$a^3(a^2)^*b^*b^4(c^2)^*c^3$$ and hence is regular.